# mocha installation error: Unexpected end of input

Tags: node.js, debugging, testing, npm, mocha.js

**I'm trying to install mocha on my windows 10 but I'm getting this error on the terminal**

```
$npm install mocha@3.0.0 --save-dev
```

`npm ERR! Unexpected end of input at 1:19983`
`npm ERR! a":"./bin/_mocha"},"directories":{},"dist":{"shasum":"653712e9852cce4`

`npm ERR!`

`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`

`npm ERR!     C:\Users\NS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-24T21_47_36_363Z-debug.log`

**this is the log file content**

`0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\NS\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'mocha@3.0.0',
1 verbose cli   '--save-dev' ]
2 info using npm@5.0.2
3 info using node@v6.10.2
4 silly install loadCurrentTree
5 silly install readLocalPackageData
6 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha 34ms (from cache)
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for mocha@3.0.0 Unexpected end of input at 1:19983
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData a":"./bin/_mocha"},"directories":{},"dist":{"shasum":"653712e9852cce4
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData                                                                      ^
8 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at 1:19983
8 verbose stack a":"./bin/_mocha"},"directories":{},"dist":{"shasum":"653712e9852cce4
8 verbose stack                                                                      ^
8 verbose stack     at SyntaxError (native)
8 verbose stack     at Object.parseJSON (C:\Users\NS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-helpfulerror\node_modules\jju\lib\parse.js:745:13)
8 verbose stack     at parse (C:\Users\NS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-helpfulerror\index.js:10:13)
8 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Users\NS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
8 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
9 verbose cwd C:\Users\NS\node-test
10 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
11 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\NS\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mocha@3.0.0" "--save-dev"
12 verbose node v6.10.2
13 verbose npm  v5.0.2
14 error Unexpected end of input at 1:19983
14 error a":"./bin/_mocha"},"directories":{},"dist":{"shasum":"653712e9852cce4
14 error                                                                      ^
15 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`

Comment: Not much help, but my node v6.11.x comes with npm v3.10.x... and it install fine on MacOS X (no Win10 to test it). Many of my projects uses mocha and i do have many users with Win10, so it really looks like something on your end.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the latest version of node

try downgrading to the LTS version

```
//
sudo npm install n -g
sudo n lts
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using it in local then use command "**npm cache clean --force**" to clear cache. Then run your command it will work